# Hide captions menu using videojs

Tags: html, video.js

using videojs to create a video player, is there a way to hide the captions menu if i have only 1 type of caption?

so instead of clicking CC, getting the menu and click on English, i want the CC button to show the caption. 
and clicking on CC again will hide the caption.

Comment: I wondered about that, too.  But, I later decided that the default behavior was perfectly fine.  (No one had any problem figuring out how to enable/disable my sub-titles.)  Beside, maybe in the future I'll want 3 choices....none, ENglish, and Spanish, etc  (I put a one-line explanation, just below the player, telling them that 'EN' meant English, and the other choice was for disable/none.)

Comment: i ended up with using my own new button to control the caption and hiding the player button

Comment: I'd really like for this to be a feature. The menu is redundant if there is only one track.